# Download Build binaries from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have a WPF project in Visual Studio Team Services. Project is successfully built, but where I can download the resulting files? I see only "Download Logs" option, but not an actual Build of my project.

[image]

[image]

```
2016-02-19T11:01:16.1495550Z Checking if artifacts directory exists: C:\a\1\a
2016-02-19T11:01:16.1505530Z Creating artifacts directory.
2016-02-19T11:01:16.1515540Z Checking if test results directory exists: C:\a\1\TestResults
2016-02-19T11:01:16.1515540Z Creating test results directory.
2016-02-19T11:01:16.1535549Z Creating binaries directory.
2016-02-19T11:01:16.2465543Z Starting: Get sources
2016-02-19T11:01:16.2595541Z Entering TfvcSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2016-02-19T11:01:16.2595541Z localPath=C:\a\1\s
2016-02-19T11:01:16.2595541Z clean=False
2016-02-19T11:01:16.2595541Z sourceVersion=C5
2016-02-19T11:01:16.2605525Z mappingJson={"mappings":[{"serverPath":"$/BuildTest","mappingType":"map","localPath":"\\"},{"serverPath":"$/BuildTest/Drops","mappingType":"cloak","localPath":"\\"}]}
2016-02-19T11:01:16.2625532Z Syncing repository: BuildTest (TFVC)
2016-02-19T11:01:16.2625532Z workspaceName=ws_1_1
2016-02-19T11:01:17.9893684Z Workspace Name: ws_1_1;Build\081c77d4-b575-42f7-b633-cce58ac8cb52
2016-02-19T11:01:18.1443685Z tf get /version:C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.4623005Z Getting C:\a\1\s;C2
2016-02-19T11:01:18.4783037Z Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates;C3
2016-02-19T11:01:18.4803012Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.4823024Z Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml;C3
2016-02-19T11:01:18.5023026Z Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml;C3
2016-02-19T11:01:18.5043058Z Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml;C4
2016-02-19T11:01:18.5063010Z Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\UpgradeTemplate.xaml;C3
2016-02-19T11:01:18.5073016Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.5083016Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.sln;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.5103012Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.vssscc;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.5293014Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\App.config;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.5303014Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\App.xaml;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.5323025Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\App.xaml.cs;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.7634440Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\MainWindow.xaml;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.7644448Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\MainWindow.xaml.cs;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.8024449Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\Properties;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.8034438Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.csproj;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.8164446Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.csproj.vspscc;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.8254935Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.8294450Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.8437313Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\Properties\Resources.resx;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.8537311Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:18.8547306Z Getting C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\Properties\Settings.settings;C5
2016-02-19T11:01:19.3223772Z Done syncing repository BuildTest to version C5 (workspace version C5)
2016-02-19T11:01:19.3223772Z Leaving TfvcSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2016-02-19T11:01:19.5182470Z Running tasks
2016-02-19T11:01:19.5472463Z Starting task: NuGet restore **\*.sln
2016-02-19T11:01:19.6352493Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.16
2016-02-19T11:01:19.7460180Z Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.16\NuGetInstaller.ps1
2016-02-19T11:01:20.4069743Z C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.sln"  -NonInteractive
2016-02-19T11:01:22.2563958Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
2016-02-19T11:01:22.5436649Z Finishing task: NuGetInstaller
2016-02-19T11:01:22.5656655Z Starting task: Build solution **\*.sln
2016-02-19T11:01:22.5826654Z C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; $env:TF_BUILD = 'True' ; Import-Module -Name 'C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.23\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.23\VSBuild.ps1'''))"
2016-02-19T11:01:25.8844051Z Build started 2/19/2016 11:01:25 AM.
2016-02-19T11:01:25.9954059Z      1>Project "C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
2016-02-19T11:01:25.9954059Z      1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2016-02-19T11:01:25.9965522Z          Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
2016-02-19T11:01:26.0714050Z        The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
2016-02-19T11:01:26.1064057Z      1>Project "C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.sln" (1) is building "C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
2016-02-19T11:01:26.1074059Z      2>PrepareForBuild:
2016-02-19T11:01:26.1084046Z          Creating directory "bin\Release\".
2016-02-19T11:01:26.1084046Z          Creating directory "obj\Release\".
2016-02-19T11:01:26.2539770Z        GenerateBindingRedirects:
2016-02-19T11:01:26.2549760Z          No suggested binding redirects from ResolveAssemblyReferences.
2016-02-19T11:01:27.5070620Z        The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
2016-02-19T11:01:27.5210619Z      2>Project "C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.csproj" (2) is building "C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\miwa0utg.tmp_proj" (3) on node 1 (_CompileTemporaryAssembly target(s)).
2016-02-19T11:01:27.5210619Z      3>CoreCompile:
2016-02-19T11:01:27.5220605Z          C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\PresentationCore.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\PresentationFramework.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xaml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\WindowsBase.dll" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\WpfApplication_Test.exe /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:winexe /utf8output App.xaml.cs MainWindow.xaml.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\obj\Release\MainWindow.g.cs C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\obj\Release\App.g.cs
2016-02-19T11:01:28.6626663Z      3>Done Building Project "C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\miwa0utg.tmp_proj" (_CompileTemporaryAssembly target(s)).
2016-02-19T11:01:29.0236662Z      2>MarkupCompilePass2:
2016-02-19T11:01:29.0236662Z          MarkupCompilePass2 successfully generated BAML or source code files.
2016-02-19T11:01:29.0246656Z        CleanupTemporaryTargetAssembly:
2016-02-19T11:01:29.0266661Z          Deleting file "obj\Release\WpfApplication_Test.exe".
2016-02-19T11:01:29.1526661Z        CoreResGen:
2016-02-19T11:01:29.1556659Z          "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\resgen.exe" /useSourcePath /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\mscorlib.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\PresentationCore.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\PresentationFramework.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Core.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xaml.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\WindowsBase.dll" /compile Properties\Resources.resx,obj\Release\WpfApplication_Test.Properties.Resources.resources
2016-02-19T11:01:29.1556659Z          Processing resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" into "obj\Release\WpfApplication_Test.Properties.Resources.resources".
2016-02-19T11:01:29.1666660Z        CoreCompile:
2016-02-19T11:01:29.1676663Z          C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\PresentationCore.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\PresentationFramework.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xaml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\WindowsBase.dll" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\WpfApplication_Test.exe /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /resource:obj\Release\WpfApplication_Test.g.resources /resource:obj\Release\WpfApplication_Test.Properties.Resources.resources /target:winexe /utf8output App.xaml.cs MainWindow.xaml.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\obj\Release\MainWindow.g.cs C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\obj\Release\App.g.cs "C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
2016-02-19T11:01:29.2226652Z        _CopyAppConfigFile:
2016-02-19T11:01:29.2236665Z          Copying file from "App.config" to "bin\Release\WpfApplication_Test.exe.config".
2016-02-19T11:01:29.2246667Z        CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
2016-02-19T11:01:29.3576655Z          Copying file from "obj\Release\WpfApplication_Test.exe" to "bin\Release\WpfApplication_Test.exe".
2016-02-19T11:01:29.3906657Z          WpfApplication_Test -> C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\bin\Release\WpfApplication_Test.exe
2016-02-19T11:01:29.3916656Z          Copying file from "obj\Release\WpfApplication_Test.pdb" to "bin\Release\WpfApplication_Test.pdb".
2016-02-19T11:01:29.4056653Z      2>Done Building Project "C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.csproj" (default targets).
2016-02-19T11:01:29.4116655Z      1>Done Building Project "C:\a\1\s\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test.sln" (default targets).
2016-02-19T11:01:29.4126658Z Build succeeded.
2016-02-19T11:01:29.4136654Z     0 Warning(s)
2016-02-19T11:01:29.4146658Z     0 Error(s)
2016-02-19T11:01:29.4166652Z Time Elapsed 00:00:03.39
2016-02-19T11:01:29.4516649Z Finishing task: VSBuild
2016-02-19T11:01:29.4656668Z Starting task: Test Assemblies **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
2016-02-19T11:01:29.4696650Z Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\VSTest\1.0.29\VSTest.ps1
2016-02-19T11:01:29.7156655Z ##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: '**\release\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**'.
2016-02-19T11:01:29.7456661Z Finishing task: VSTest
2016-02-19T11:01:29.7616661Z Starting task: Publish symbols path: 
2016-02-19T11:01:29.7626667Z C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; $env:TF_BUILD = 'True' ; Import-Module -Name 'C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishSymbols\1.0.19\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishSymbols\1.0.19\PublishSymbols.ps1'''))"
2016-02-19T11:01:31.5836666Z Found 1 files.
2016-02-19T11:01:33.7377997Z Finishing task: PublishSymbols
2016-02-19T11:01:33.7458003Z Starting task: Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
2016-02-19T11:01:33.7548017Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.11
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3034401Z ##[debug]check path : C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.11\task.json
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3044405Z ##[debug]set resource file to: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.11\task.json
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3054404Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3054404Z ##[debug]load strings from: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.11\task.json
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3064406Z ##[debug]load loc strings from: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.11\strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3064406Z ##[debug]Contents=**\bin\release\**
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3064406Z ##[debug]SourceFolder=C:\a\1\s
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3064406Z ##[debug]check path : C:\a\1\s
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3064406Z ##[debug]TargetFolder=C:\a\1\a
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3064406Z ##[debug]CleanTargetFolder=false
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3094396Z ##[debug]OverWrite=false
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3094396Z ##[debug]include content pattern: **\bin\release\**
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3344402Z ##[debug]find C:\a\1\s
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3364402Z ##[debug]83 matches.
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3414986Z ##[debug]allFiles contains 57 files
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3414986Z ##[debug]Include matching C:\a\1\s\**\bin\release\**
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3454396Z ##[debug]Include matched 3 files
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3508941Z ##[debug]load strings from: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.11\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\lib.json
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3514399Z ##[debug]load loc strings from: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.11\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3514399Z found 3 files
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3524401Z ##[debug]file:C:/a/1/s/WpfApplication_Test/WpfApplication_Test/bin/Release/WpfApplication_Test.exe will be copied.
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3524401Z ##[debug]file:C:/a/1/s/WpfApplication_Test/WpfApplication_Test/bin/Release/WpfApplication_Test.exe.config will be copied.
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3534417Z ##[debug]file:C:/a/1/s/WpfApplication_Test/WpfApplication_Test/bin/Release/WpfApplication_Test.pdb will be copied.
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3534417Z ##[debug]path exists: C:\a\1\a
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3544394Z ##[debug]Creating folder C:\a\1\a\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\bin\Release
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3544394Z ##[debug]creating path: C:\a\1\a\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\bin\Release
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3554401Z Copying C:/a/1/s/WpfApplication_Test/WpfApplication_Test/bin/Release/WpfApplication_Test.exe to C:\a\1\a\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\bin\Release\WpfApplication_Test.exe
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3574405Z Copying C:/a/1/s/WpfApplication_Test/WpfApplication_Test/bin/Release/WpfApplication_Test.exe.config to C:\a\1\a\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\bin\Release\WpfApplication_Test.exe.config
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3594402Z Copying C:/a/1/s/WpfApplication_Test/WpfApplication_Test/bin/Release/WpfApplication_Test.pdb to C:\a\1\a\WpfApplication_Test\WpfApplication_Test\bin\Release\WpfApplication_Test.pdb
2016-02-19T11:01:34.3734385Z Finishing task: CopyFiles
2016-02-19T11:01:34.4030377Z Starting task: Publish Artifact: drop
2016-02-19T11:01:34.4064466Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7070047Z ##[debug]check path : C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26\task.json
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7090146Z ##[debug]set resource file to: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26\task.json
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7090146Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7100054Z ##[debug]load strings from: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26\task.json
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7110042Z ##[debug]load loc strings from: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.26\strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7110042Z ##[debug]system.hosttype=build
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7120054Z ##[debug]PathtoPublish=C:\a\1\a
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7120054Z ##[debug]check path : C:\a\1\a
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7130056Z ##[debug]ArtifactName=drop
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7130056Z ##[debug]ArtifactType=Container
2016-02-19T11:01:34.7140051Z ##[debug]TargetPath=\\my\share\Test_01\20160219.1
2016-02-19T11:01:35.0973937Z Max Concurrent Uploads 2, Max Creators 1
2016-02-19T11:01:35.1693927Z Found 3 files to upload.
2016-02-19T11:01:35.1773928Z Files found locally 3,
2016-02-19T11:01:35.1773928Z Files evaluated 3,
2016-02-19T11:01:35.1773928Z Files left to evaluate 0.,
2016-02-19T11:01:35.1783907Z Files created without upload 0,
2016-02-19T11:01:35.1793899Z Files uploaded 0
2016-02-19T11:01:35.1793899Z Files left to process 3
2016-02-19T11:01:35.1803898Z ---------------------------
2016-02-19T11:01:37.1843094Z Created 0 files without uploading content. Total files processed 3
2016-02-19T11:01:37.1873257Z Uploaded artifact 'C:\a\1\a' to container folder 'drop' of build 19.
2016-02-19T11:01:37.2918886Z Associated artifact 17 with build 19
2016-02-19T11:01:37.2968843Z Finishing task: PublishBuildArtifacts
```

Comment: Added log from my build

Comment: Looks like the build configuration parameter of the Visual Studio build task isn't set... I don't see a `/p:configuration=release` in the call to msbuild.exe nor csc.exe.

Comment: I went through the whole VSTS but I can't find configuration for this option. 
And where are those builded files actually stored?

Comment: Check the build with visual studio task. It has a configuration and platform property. I suspect neither is set.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the logs, the build result files has been uploaded. You can click "Artifacts" link to download these files:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eddie. Your solution works perfect for my situation.

Answer (score 4):

Have you added a **Publish Build Artifacts** or **Copy and Publish Build Artifacts** task at the end of your build? Only if you publish the items you want to keep at the end, are the outputs of the builds kept.

[image]

Since your Copy action includes the `$(buildconfiguration)` variable in the source folder mask, make sure that the Visual Studio Build task uses this same variable.

Comment: I added screenshots of my "Copy Files" and "Publish Build Artidacts". But I have no idea what i should changed here a where i can find builded files.

Comment: Check this post: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/build/artifacts

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have changed a bit lately and I had a hard time finding it.  Hopefully, this helps someone else find it quickly.

On the build page, Select Artifacts -> drop.  The drop popup will show then you can right click and get a menu to download.

[Download artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5woes.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Location of build artifacts has been changed again. Navigate to Pipelines, Pipelines, select build run and click on link under Artifacts section. On Published artifacts page, there is link to download artifacts

[image]

[image]